# Discrete math. How many one to one functions satisfy the following property.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Consider the set $A=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and let B be the power set of A. 
So the question is: 
How many one to one functions $f:A\to B$ are there, such that $1 ∉ f(1), 2 ∉ f(2)$?
I am having a really hard time with this problem, I spent a few hours giving it a thought but I really don´t have a clue.
Thanks!

Comment: Here you are taking $6$ independent choices of subsets... so count how many ways you can choose each subset and then multiply them.

Comment: The hard bit is that you only want injective functions.   Inclusion-Exclusion will work, though it looks a little tricky to count the injective functions that violate both restrictions.

Comment: @lulu: exactly the only functions that I want are injective functions

Answer (score 1):

Start with $f(1)$. There are$32$ choices, $16$ of which include $2$ and $16$ that do not. For the ones that include $2$ you have $32$ choices for $f(2)$, for the others $31$. So there are $16(31+32)$ choices for the first two, then $62$ for $f(3)$ and so on

Comment: for f(3) there are 2^6-2 choices, for f(4) there are 2^6-3 choices, for f(5) there are 2^6-4, for f(6) there are 2^6-5 choices. Now when it comes to the f(1) I think that the right answer is {2,3,4,5,6}=2^5 choices, so the same for f(2) with {1,3,4,5,6}=2^5 choices. But the thing is for f(2) are there 2^5 choices or 2^5-1?